# How to assign targets to everyone but target can't be yourself or two people targeting each other

Tags: lua, roblox

Creating a game on Roblox but a problem I'm having is making sure everyone has a target that isn't themself or someone who already targets them.

Say if you had 4 players assigned targets randomly. I want to prevent this outcome.

Player1 targets Player2

Player2 targets Player3

Player3 targets Player1

Player4 targets Player4

or Player3 targets Player4

Player4 targets Player3

```
function aFunctionfdfsd()
local targetList = {} -- List of people(3+) who haven't been targeted

while myTarget == Me or myTarget == targetsMe do  -- cant be yourself or exchanged
    ranPlayer = math.random(1, #targetList)
    myTarget = targetList[ranPlayer]


    --HELP HERE ?

end


table.remove(targetList, targetList[ranPlayer])

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reliable method could just be to offset each player by a fixed amount to give you their target.

*Round 1) offset = 1*

- Player 1 targets Player 2
- Player 2 targets Player 3
- Player 3 targets Player 4
- Player 4 targets Player 1

*Round 2) offset = 2*

- Player 1 targets Player 3
- Player 2 targets Player 4
- Player 3 targets Player 1
- Player 4 targets Player 2

Etc.

Once offset is equal to the number of players, you just reset it back to one. And if you've got players joining and leaving it will be hard for players to spot the pattern. Or you could just shuffle the player list every round.

```
-- keep track of the current offset
local offset = 1

-- get a mapping of players to targets
local function getTargetsForRound()
    local targets = {}

    local playerList = game.Players:GetPlayers()
    for i, player in ipairs(playerList) do
        -- calculate the target index and correct for 1-based arrays
        local targetIndex
        if i + offset > #playerlist then
            targetIndex = (i + offset) % #playerList
        else
            targetIndex = i + offset
        end
        targets[ player.Name ] = playList[ targetIndex ].Name
    end

     -- increment the offset for next time
     offset = offset + 1
     if offset == #playersList then
         offset = 1
     end
end

-- at the start of every round, fetch the next targets
local t = getTargetsForRound()

for playerName, targetName in pairs(t) do
    print( string.format("%s's target is %s", playerName, targetName )
end
```

Comment: Wouldn’t the player eventually target themself

Offset = 0

Player1: targetIndex = ((1 + 0) % 2) + 1 = 2

Player2: targetIndex = ((2 + 0) % 2) + 1 = 1

Offset = 1

Player1:  targetIndex = ((1 + 1) % 2) + 1 = 1

Player2: targetIndex = ((2 + 1) % 2) + 1 = 2

It does the same with 3 players after 3 rounds.

Comment: Would adding this line fix it: if offset == #playersList-1 then
  offset = 0
 end

Comment: You're right, my late night math is off. Let me update with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1)

Create a local copy of target list and remove the targeting player from the target list.
Then pick a target from the reduced target list.

```
local myTargetList = {}
for i,v in ipairs(targetList) do
  if v != Me then
    table.insert(myTargetList, v)
  end
end
-- pick target from myTargetList instead of targetList
```

Option 2)

Pick a random target until the target is not the targeting player.

Comment: Random selection can still lead to the undesired outcome described in the problem. When you randomly choose, the last player in the list has a chance to only be able to target themselves or duplicate an existing target.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a bit of recursion and randomness in my solution.

In the code below you pass in the list of player names (ie. `game.PLayers:getChildren()`) and the code will then randomly match them to other players. It has checks to ensure they can't match themselves or an already taken target and if you are left with the last guy having no targets to chose it will call itself to get a new list.

As the seed I use is truly random you have no danger of getting stuck in a recursive loop from this as the next loop is always different.

```lua
function stayOnTarget(players)
    math.randomseed(tonumber(tostring({}):sub(8))) --Very reliable random seed
    local availableTargets = {}
    local choosenTargets = {}

    --Duplicating players array without linking them
    for _, player in pairs(players) do
        table.insert(availableTargets, player)
    end

    for i, player in pairs(players) do
        --If the last player is left with themselves, try again
        if i == #players and availableTargets[1] == player then
            return stayOnTarget(players)
        end

        --Pick a target that is not themselves
        local targetIndex = math.random(1, #availableTargets)
        local target = availableTargets[targetIndex]
        while target == player do
            targetIndex = math.random(1, #availableTargets)
            target = availableTargets[targetIndex]
        end

        --Store target and remove them from available targets
        choosenTargets[player] = target
        table.remove(availableTargets, targetIndex)
    end
    return choosenTargets
end
local results = stayOnTarget({"User1", "User2", "User3", "User4"})

--Print target matches
for i, v in pairs(results) do
    print(i .. " = " .. v)
end
```

At the end a dictionary is returned and I have set up a look to print the results if you want to see them. If you have any issues just leave a comment.